# Pandas multi index :select column based on index number

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a multi indexed dataframe that has 2 index levels on the columns.

I can select columns based on their names, that works perfectly :

```
df.loc[:, (['Level 0 column name'], ['Level 1 first column name', 'Level 1 second column name'])]
```

However, I can't select columns based on their number, for example :

```
df.loc[:, (0, ['Level 1 first column name', 'Level 1 second column name'])]
```

I get a KeyError: 0  error

Same problem with :

```
df.iloc[:, (0, ['Level 1 first column name', 'Level 1 second column name'])]
```

I get IndexingError: Too many indexers

Is this even possible ?
I could not find this kind of selection in the documentation : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index

Sorry for not having a basic complete code, it's not easy for me to reproduce

Thanks

Comment: See the [Using slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers) section. You can use `.loc`. _You can provide any of the selectors as if you are indexing by label, see Selection by Label, including slices, lists of labels, labels, and boolean indexers._

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I can see this section is only about "label" indexing, whereas my problem is to filter by column number... or am I missing something ?

Comment: That’s the point, you can only do that with labels.

Comment: I can select columns based on their labels, that works perfectly as shown on my original message. So if I understand well, selecting columns by number is impossible with multi indexing

Comment: That is correct